# ERR_CERT_INVALID when amplify app calls elasticbeanstalk backend with self-signed cert

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my ui in aws amplify.  The ui calls some backend api deployed in elastiv beanstalk.  Since aws amplify url is `https`, it cannot call the api in aws eb since it is in `http`.  So I created a self-signed certificcate and set it in the application load balancer in the EB configuration.  But when the ui calls the api, now in `https`, I got this `ERR_CERT_INVALID`.

Please advise.

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0):

> self-signed certificcate

You **can't use self-signed** cert. You need valid public SSL certificate from a reputable provided, such as AWS ACM. For that you **must** have you own domain. You can't use default EB domain provided by AWS to obtain  a valid SSL certificate.

The alternative is to front you EB with CloudFront. CF by default will give you a HTTPS endpoint. But without a valid SSL certificate for your EB and domain, all traffic between CF and EB will be **unencrypted**.

Comment: is it possible to use let's encrypt on eb?

Comment: @iPhoneJavaDev Yes, but you still need your own domain.

Comment: I have exact same issue. I have my own domain, mapped it to ec2 IPv4, and installed Letsencrypt SSL successfully. But when amplify UI hits EC2 API it gives net::ERR_CERT_INVALID. I checked my domain with this tool https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html , certificate is valid until next 3 months still I get the certificate error. Any help?